# Drupal 7 views contextual filter restrict content based on current users role

Tags: drupal-7, view, arguments

I'd like to restrict access to a view based on the CURRENT users role. Not the author. For example, if a user has the authorized user role then they can see the content of the view. If a user is anonymous then they are shown the No Results Behavior of the view. I can't believe there is no way to do this. I know there is the Access settings, but I don't want the anonymous user given an access denied message.

Answer (score 0):

One method I can think of:

Use hook_views_query_alter(). Check if the current user belongs to the set of roles you are interested in. If he doesn't, add a condition which is always false, such as 0 = 1. To see how to add such a condition in code, see the example on this page: http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7. The resulting view will not have any result on adding this condition.

Neerav Mehta.
[Drupal Development](http://redcrackle.com)

Comment: For the record, I solved this using Panel Pages and selection rules.